# How to play 720p video in Fedora 20 if necessary plugin not found?

Tags: fedora, video, media

I tried to play an 720p video in the default video player in Fedora 20, but it couldn't play it. It shows that a plugin is needed to play this file format and searches it online, and says that there is no such plugin.

Is there any other way to configure the default player or suggest me another media player which can play 720p video mp4 format?

Comment: You'll likely want to add the output of this command to your Q: `ffmpeg -i file.mp4`.

Comment: @sim I tried to enter that command in terminal but it showed me error

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Take a look at the various software to install on this guide: http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2013/12/fedora-20-heisenbug-post-installation.html. There are directions for setting up video etc. in Fedora, I'd start with those.

Comment: Follow slm's suggestion. I always install and play everything with Videolan VLC as it comes with all the plug-ins I needed (even back in the days I was using Windows).

Answer (score 1):

install VLC Or Whaaw! Media Player
1.for vlc copy this code on terminal and hit enter

> su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck
>   http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm
>   -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm
>   -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'

then paste this code on terminal and press enter

> su -c 'yum install vlc'

2.to install whaaw! media player search its rpm in google